# Best practice to safely persist user data to minify API calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, cookies, local-storage

I have a react app with a rails backend. Users must be logged in to use certain functionality or must be premium users to access premium functionality.

My app makes an API call to the backend on every page load to check if the user is logged in and if so sets the state of the react app to include the user object the API sends as response and sets `loggedInStatus: "LOGGED_IN"`.

The app uses the state and user object to accordingly allow or prohibit functionality.
This means though that on every page load an API call must be made which seems inefficient to me.

An alternative could be to store the data in `localStorage` and only make API calls and update the user object in `localStorage` if changes were made to the user. However, storing information like email addresses in `localStorage` doesn't seem very safe to me.

Is there a way / best practice to securely store and retrieve senstive information without the need for API calls on every page load? Please excuse if this questions seems rather broad, I don't know how to phrase it better.

Comment: It's absolutely fine to make that call on every page load, it's not an expensive call usually. Don't optimize prematurely!

Comment: I believe its completely ok, to store basic user informations like email or username in localstorage. Using cookie can be an alternative.

Comment: Even if you save some data in localStorage, you should still be authorizing every request against your protected resources in your api, otherwise it could be dangerous. Check the basic JWT workflow for example.